# Moduli space and Teichmüller space of genus 2 surface

Tags: reference-request, geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

What are the moduli space and Teichmüller space of a genus two compact orientable surface?

What is the difference between them?

Can anyone provide some references for these?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Teichmüller space is ${\Bbb C}^3$ and the moduli space is its quotient by the action of the mapping class grou

Comment: Can you explain Why?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking. Without editing your post to explain your mathematical background, we have no idea where to start an answer, and your question risks being closed. At a bare minimum, you should explain what you already know regarding the general definitions of the Teichmüller space and moduli space.

Comment: I suggest you read the Wikipedia pages for Teichmuller space and moduli space and think about what you do and don’t understand. This may help you form a more focused question?

Comment: The question "what are" is ambiguous: Are you asking about the definition? Are you asking about an identification with some spaces that you are familiar with?

Comment: @ MoisheKohan yes I asking about an identification of it with some familiar spaces and I want to know how that identification came.

Comment: Still unclear: "An identification as what"? As a topological space? As a complex manifold?  In the latter case (almost surely), there will be no "familiar to you space" that identifies holomorphically with the  genus 2 Teichmuller space.

Comment: @MoisheKohan As a topological space.